# Which Windows mp3 player software can be installed without administrator rights?

Tags: windows-7, mp3, administrator, mp3-player

On my company computer running Windows 7, I don't have administrator rights, so both iTunes and Winamp refuse to install. Is there any decent mp3 player software I can install anyway? Bonus points for those players which can read an iTunes library without a lengthy conversion/scanning process.

Comment: Is this okay with your network admins?  It's not worth losing your job over some background music.

Comment: Good thought! In my case, the admins don't mind - colleagues also listen to music (with headphones, of course). I also don't put the mp3 files on the company computer, but keep them on my own external hard drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look at some of the applications mentioned at [portableapps.com](http://portableapps.com). These are stand-alone apps that can be run from, for example, an USB stick and do not require installation.

Comment: +1, was about to suggest this, very useful for all kinds of applications. Check their [apps](http://portableapps.com/apps) page and scroll down to the "music and video" section for a selection.

Answer (score 1):

- Try portable
   [VLC](http://www.softpedia.com/get/PORTABLE-SOFTWARE/Multimedia/Video/Portable-VLC-Media-Player.shtml)
- Try this standalone media player  [XULPlayer](http://xulplayer.sourceforge.net/). No need to install

[image]

- Go  [here](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-windows.html) and downlad  zipped version of vlc . just extract it , no installation required

Answer (score 1):

There's a usb install option for [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) as of the latest version. Considering an itunes library is really just a folder, just point whicherver you choose and it, and you'll be good

Answer (score 0):

I've always liked coolplayer, just a single .exe
http://coolplayer.sourceforge.net/